# Mathematica help with NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, education

[image]I am fairly new to mathematica and I'm trying to generate an SIS s-wave IV plot using the formulae in the attached image. Could I get some help in fixing the issue? [image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please post code, not images. As [@yarchick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9469/yarchik) says "When you want your car to be repaired, you bring it to a workshop, not just show a photo to the mechanics. When you want your question to be answered, you post your code, not just a photo of it"

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Clear[delta,gamma,z,e,beta];
delta=0.01;gamma=0.1;z=e-I*gamma;beta=1;
f[x_]:=1/(1+Exp[beta x]);
sbcs[e_]:=Re[z]/(z^2-delta^2)^(1/2);
s[v_]:=NIntegrate[sbcs[e]f'[e-v],{e,-5,5}];
Plot[ReIm[s[v]],{v,-1.005,1.005}]
```

See if that plot exactly matches what the textbooks say that it should be.

Then compare that character by character with what you have and try to figure out exactly why the differences are there. If you can't figure out why a change is there then change that single bit back to what you had and try it again and see what happens.

Be very careful to remember that Mathematica keeps a cache of previous assignments and will use that memory until you restart Mathematica or assign a different value or specifically tell it to forget a particular assignment. If you don't keep that in mind you can get results minutes or hours later that you do not realize depends on an assignment you made earlier.